# Client-side OAuth2 without user authentication (service calls)

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0

So I would like to distribute an API to websites as a Javascript plugin (for ease of integration/use) which would communicate, through OAuth2, with the service I provide.

I learned that the `Implicit` grant type is usually recommended for client/browser-based apps, however in this case I don't want the end user to authenticate. The only *user* that should communicate with my service is the one associated with the website: in other words, the API calls should always be made on behalf of the user who created the OAuth2 client app, as opposed to the person browsing the website.

The `Client Credentials` grant type would seem appropriate for this use-case, however it implies sending the client secret in OAuth2 requests, which doesn't seem safe at all when it comes from Javascript.

Is there any good/common way of achieving this? I'm kinda new to OAuth2 so I may be having the wrong approach.

Many thanks in advance,

Jérémy

Comment: i dont get your problem? Deliver a token to the *client* that has logged in with OAuth, then use it to auth *users* ...

Comment: @Jonas I'm not sure what you mean. To be delivered a token, the client needs to authenticate using a client ID/client secret. I don't want them to be in the JS script and visible from the page source.